# react-form-validator not registering children components?

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, validation

I am using `'react-form-validator-core'` package and trying to create a custom form validator that implements `'mui-downshift'`, a Material UI implementation of PayPal's downshift. This question is mostly about `'react-form-validator-core'` package itself. The problem is that the form itself does not register the validator component I've created. Here is my full code of the custom component and the form itself. I've exhausted my debugging skills, but what I noticed is that there's something wrong with the `this.context` in the form...

### Validator component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import MuiDownshift from 'mui-downshift';
import { ValidatorComponent } from 'react-form-validator-core';


class AutocompleteValidator extends ValidatorComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        debugger;
        super(props);

        this.originalItems = props.items.map(({key, name}) => ({ text: name, value: key }));

        this.handleStateChange = this.handleStateChange.bind(this);
        this.errorText = this.errorText.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        if (!this.filteredItems) {
            this.setState({filteredItems: this.originalItems});
        }

        if (!!this.props.value) {
            const selectedItem = this.originalItems.filter(
                item => item.value.toLowerCase().includes(this.props.value.toLowerCase())
            )[0];
            this.setState({ selectedItem })
        } else {
            this.setState({ selectedItem: null})
        }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        // If no filteredItems in sate, get the whole list:
        if (!nextProps.value) {
            this.setState({ isValid: false })
        }

    }

    handleStateChange(changes) {
        // If searching
        if (changes.hasOwnProperty('inputValue')) {
            const filteredItems = this.originalItems.filter(
                item => item.text.toLowerCase().includes(changes.inputValue.toLowerCase())
            );
            this.setState({ filteredItems })
        }

        // If something is selected
        if (changes.hasOwnProperty('selectedItem')) {
            !!changes.selectedItem ? this.setState({isValid: true}) : this.setState({isValid: false})
            // If we get undefined, change to '' as a fallback to default state
            changes.selectedItem = changes.selectedItem ? changes.selectedItem : '';
            this.props.onStateChange(changes);
        }
    }

    errorText() {
        const { isValid } = this.state;

        if (isValid) {
            return null;
        }

        return (
            <div style={{ color: 'red' }}>
                {this.getErrorMessage()}
            </div>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MuiDownshift
                    {...this.props}
                    items={this.state.filteredItems}
                    onStateChange={this.handleStateChange}
                    ref={(r) => { this.input = r; }}
                    defaultSelectedItem={this.state.selectedItem}
                />
                {this.errorText()}
            </div>
        );
    }

}
AutocompleteValidator.childContextTypes = {
  form: PropTypes.object
};

export default AutocompleteValidator;
```

### A component where it's used:

```
    render() {
        return (
            <ValidatorForm
                ref='form'
                onSubmit={() => {
                    this.context.router.history.push(this.props.config.urls['step5']);
                }}
                onError={errors => console.log(errors)}
            >
                <Row>
                    <Col md={12}>
                        <AutocompleteValidator
                            validators={['required']}
                            errorMessages={['Cette information doit être renseignée']}
                            isRequired={true}
                            name='bankId'
                            items={this.props.config.list.bank}
                            onStateChange={(changes) => {
                                this.props.loansUpdate('bankId', changes.selectedItem.value);
                            }}
                            value={!!this.props.loans.bankId ? this.props.loans.bankId : false}
                        />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Col md={12} style={{ marginTop: '15px' }}>
                        <Checkbox
                            label={<Translate value='step4.insuranceProvidedByBank' />}
                            labelStyle={{ 'top': '0px' }}
                            name='insuranceProvidedByBank'
                            value={this.props.loans.insuranceProvidedByBank}
                            checked={this.props.loans.insuranceProvidedByBank}
                            onCheck={(event, value) => {
                                this.props.loansUpdate('insuranceProvidedByBank', value);
                            }}
                        />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Col sm={6} md={5}>
                        <Button
                            fullWidth
                            style={{ marginTop: '50px', marginBottom: '20px' }}
                            type='submit'
                            icon={<i className='fa fa-angle-right' style={{ marginLeft: '10px', display: 'inline-block' }} />}
                        ><Translate value='iContinue' /></Button>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </ValidatorForm >
        )
   };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you get this problem because you override default `componentWillMount` and `componentWillReceiveProps` methods from [ValidatorComponent](https://github.com/NewOldMax/react-form-validator-core/blob/master/src/ValidatorComponent.jsx). So, to solve this case you should do something like this

```
    componentWillMount() {
        // should call parent method before
        super.componentWillMount();
        // your code
    }
```